# Single line query for copying data from 3 tables to a empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, database-performance

Today in interview, I was asked, if I can write a single query to copy data from 3 tables to an empty table.

I started saying, I will use temp table or table variables but he said no, he wants to see in a single statement or query.... I was blank :(

Do any of you can share the right answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into <emplty_table>
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
```

provided all the table have the same structure

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you, what if I have Union in the second table insert ? Why you use Union :( I dont understand.

Comment: Also Joe, one of our mate below used "Joins" Could you please elaborate when to use joins and when to use Union and whats the difference performance wise :( I am newbie :(

Comment: @Divine: when you use union between two tables , it will combine all the records from both the table and eliminate duplicate records if any and also sort it. whereas union all will just combine the two tables.. In your case I think union all is enough.. union all is much faster than union. Please read more on the net

Comment: union and join are two different operations.. union combines  records "vertically"(not a technical term, I made it up for understanding) whereas join combines records "horizontally"..please read more on the net

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the specifics, but in general I think the idea would be to use a union. The following is obviously pseudocode, but it conveys the idea:

```
insert into x (field1, field2, field3)
  select a, b, c
    from table1
  union
  select d, e, f
    from table2
  union
  select g, h, i
    from table3
```